# How to load JSON information (get weather) and reload tableView, with a saved list of cities?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am a beginner trying to make a weather App similar to the default weather App on the iphone. I am currently working on the screen that stores a list of cities made by the user. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have made the tableView work, once they select a cell, it dismisses the tableViewController and loads that cities weather on the previous screen. However I am now trying to add a Temperature label to the tableViewcell next to each city name.

The top cell displays current Location and is used to get weather of their current location

I know I am getting the weather via Print statements, however I am having trouble reloading the tableView once I have it. Right now the idea I am trying to do is to grab the saved city names stored with coreData and use those city names to get their weather data via a JSON. Then use the json to display the city name and city temperature.

I have tried putting the tableview.reload() in many different areas. 
I have moved the call for the functions that get the weather data to different spots. Nothing I have tried works.

```
let cityClassModel = [CityClass()]
var x = 0

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var savedCitiesArray = [SavedCityEntity]()
var savedDelegate : SavedCityChangeDelegate?
var isCelsius = true
var isCelsiusThree : Bool? {
    didSet{
        isCelsius = false
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!


//****************************************************************************

override func viewDidLoad() {

    loadCities()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = 65.0
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none


    // cycle through array and get weather data for each stored city
    if savedCitiesArray.count > 0 {

        while x < savedCitiesArray.count {

            let cityParams : [String : String] = ["q" : savedCitiesArray[x].cityName!, "appid" : APP_ID]
            getTemperatures(url: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL, parameters: cityParams, cityNumber: x)
x +=1
        }

    //print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


 //********************************************************************

 // MARK: - Get City Temperature
func getTemperatures(url: String, parameters: [String : String], cityNumber: Int) {

     Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
         (response) in

         if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success got the weather data for cityList!")

            let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.updateTemperature(json: weatherJSON, cityNumber: cityNumber)
             //print(weatherJSON)

         } else {

             //print("Error \(response.result.error)")
             print("Connection Issues")
         }
     }

 }

 //MARK: - JSON Parsing
 /**************************************************************************/

func updateTemperature(json : JSON, cityNumber: Int) {

     //get current temperature
     if let tempResult = json["main"]["temp"].double {

        cityClassModel[cityNumber].cityClassName = json["name"].stringValue
         //update data model temperature
        cityClassModel[cityNumber].cityClassTemp = String(Int(tempResult - 273.15))

        print("got temperature for cityList - \(cityClassModel[cityNumber].cityClassName) \(cityClassModel[cityNumber].cityClassTemp)")

     } else {
         // if for some reason unable to get weather data
         print("Weather Unavailable")
     }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

//****************************************************************************

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
//****************************************************************************
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return savedCitiesArray.count + 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //declare cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cityListCell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell

    cell.delegate = self
    // current location cell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Current Location"
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        let cellBackgroundColour = HexColor(hexString: "2A5488")

        if let color = cellBackgroundColour.darken(byPercentage: ((CGFloat(indexPath.row) / CGFloat(savedCitiesArray.count))) * 5) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(complementaryFlatColorOf: color, withAlpha: 0.4)
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: color, returnFlat: true)
        }
    }
    // if cell is not the current location cell
    else if indexPath.row <= savedCitiesArray.count {

        var city = ""
        var temp = ""

        if cityClassModel[0].cityClassName != "" {

        city = cityClassModel[indexPath.row - 1].cityClassName
        temp = cityClassModel[indexPath.row - 1].cityClassTemp

        }

        cell.setCity(city: city, Temperature: temp)

        cell.accessoryType = .none
        let cellBackgroundColour = HexColor(hexString: "2A5488")

        if let color = cellBackgroundColour.darken(byPercentage: ((CGFloat(indexPath.row) / CGFloat(savedCitiesArray.count)))) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(complementaryFlatColorOf: color, withAlpha: 0.4)
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: color, returnFlat: true)
        }

    }

    return cell
}



//MARK: - city SELECTED in menu then becomes city in weatherView
//****************************************************************************
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       // IF CURRENT LOCATION IS SELECTED
       if indexPath.row == 0 {
           //1 Get the city name the user entered in the text field
           let cityName = "currentLocation"
           //2 If we have a delegate set, call the method userEnteredANewCityName
           savedDelegate?.userSelectedANewCity(city: cityName, units: isCelsius)
           //3 dismiss the Change City View Controller to go back to the WeatherViewController
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           print("Current Location Cell Clicked")
       }
       // IF A NEW CITY IS SELECTED
       else if indexPath.row <= savedCitiesArray.count {
           //1 Get the city name the user entered in the text field
           let cityName = savedCitiesArray[indexPath.row - 1].cityName!
           //2 If we have a delegate set, call the method userEnteredANewCityName
           savedDelegate?.userSelectedANewCity(city: cityName, units: isCelsius)
           //3 dismiss the Change City View Controller to go back to the WeatherViewController
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }


// MARK: - Save,Load, and Delete Functions
//****************************************************************************

//Save function (save city to list)
func saveCities() {
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving city/context \(error)")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

//Load City from Data Model
func loadCities () {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<SavedCityEntity> = SavedCityEntity.fetchRequest()
    do {
        savedCitiesArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
}

//delete data from swipe
func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
            context.delete(savedCitiesArray[indexPath.row - 1])
            savedCitiesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row - 1)
            saveCities()
            }
```

Cells appear blank. (I originally was able to get just the city names from coreData and populate the cells with them) but since trying to add the city names with temperature I now get nothing.

Ideally each cell would display the city name and current temperature there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the delegete and datasource in your viewDidLoad()... try:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

or you set them in the interface builder?

Comment: I added this and it fixed the issue! Thanks, I had it there and must have removed it at some point by accident! Our of curiosity do you know why my post is getting negative votes (it's at -2) this was my first post on here. Did I do something frowned upon?

Comment: You're welcome..Yep.. you can read this to solve your doubt https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212064/why-do-i-get-negative-votes-on-all-of-my-questions

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.reloadData()` won't be called if `delegate` and `dataSource` isn't set.

Add this lines to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // do other staffs
   tableView.delegate = self
   tableView.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: I added this and it fixed the issue! Thanks, I had it there and must have removed it at some point by accident! Our of curiosity do you know why my post is getting negative votes (it's at -2) this was my first post on here. Did I do something frowned upon?